# VSCode Breakpoints are disabled when launching a test run

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-debugger

I have the following setup in my **launch.json** configuration:

```
{
  "type": "node-terminal",
  "name": "Test Current File",
  "request": "launch",
  "command": "npm run test:unit ${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

I am able to run the current file, but any breakpoints defined are disabled

Setting up the Breakpoint

[image: Before Running]

Selecting the Launch configuration

[image: Running Current File]

While Test is Running

[image: Breakpoints disabled]

End of Test (ran but no breakpoints)

[image: Test Running]